# Add existing UIViewControllers screens to single screen which has UISegmentedControl in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

My swift project has many screens with xib and related swift files. Now I am designing initial screen which has UISegmentedControl at the bottom. UISegmentedControl has 2 segments, that is home screen and my profile screen. I have both home screen and my profile screen designed. I want to add both these screens to Initial screen. I have tried following code to add screens to initial screen view but it throws error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
Code i have tried:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") 
self.addChildViewController(controller)
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_SIZE.width, SCREEN_SIZE.height)
self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

**Solution:**

On click home segement

```
 let homeViewController: HomeViewController = HomeViewController()
    homeViewController.loadView()
    homeViewController.viewDidLoad()
    homeViewController.view.frame = self.subView1.bounds;
    self.subView1.addSubview(homeViewController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(homeViewController)
    menuViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

On click my profile segment:

```
let profileViewController: ProfileViewController = ProfileViewController()
   profileViewController.loadView()
   profileViewController.viewDidLoad()
   profileViewController.view.frame = self.subView2.bounds;
   self.subView2.addSubview(profileViewController.view)
   self.addChildViewController(profileViewController)
   profileViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't have *screens*, you have *views* (UIViews) controlled by *view controllers* (UIViewControllers. This may seem insignificant, but it really isn't. The main reason, is a UISegmentedControl is a subview of a single view (and yes, a single view controller). Now that we have the basics out of the way, search on this site for "Swift unwrapping Optional" - you'll find several - close to hundreds - of questions on the error. I would normally ask what line you are receiving the error on, but I know - it's the only one you are trying to do a forced unwrap on.

Comment: Finally, consider replacing your UISegmentedControl - at the bottom of the screen - with a UINavigationController. If you are working in Interface Builder it's quite easy. Search on that and I'll bet you'll find a much better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @dfd if i use UINavigationController it will load whole view. I want Home and My Profile buttons(UISegmentedControl)  should stay as it is at the bottom when i navigate between home and profile.

Comment: Then if I'm reading your design properly, the right route to go is not three view controllers, each with their own view - but rather a single view controller with (1) a UISegmentedControl at the bottom and (2) two subviews in the main (container?) view. You can easily refactor much of the VC code into the views or other classes.

Comment: @dfd I want to reuse exiting 2 two controllers into the new controller which has UISegmentedControl at the bottom. Question is how to reuse them as subview.